# How to handle iOS consumable in-app purchase refunds

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, itunes-store

I'm trying to handle in-app purchase consumable refunds.

I've been researching about this and the only thing I could find was we need to validate the receipt and check for cancellation_date on the receipt.

Is there any update on Apple side perhaps a callback that notify us when refund happens? It is ridiculous for us to keep checking cancellation_date. This could be too many requests as we scale, also not sure if Apple will block our request if we make too many validation request.

In addition, what do you guys do if the user already use that consumable? Is it worth to undo all the actions they did? For example, I've seen apps that have like coins that they use to tip other users within the app. Redoing all this seems like a mess.

How do we protect ourselves from this fraud?

Thank you!

Comment: If a consumable purchase is refunded by Apple there is no way of finding out from the receipt. The cancellation date is just for auto renewing subscriptions.  Basically if Apple refunds a consumable purchase then the person gets to keep the consumables and they get their money back.

Comment: Also, it seems likely that "tipping" using consumable items would violate 3.1.1 of the App Store guidelines; "Apps should not directly or indirectly enable gifting of in-app purchase content, features, or consumable items to other"

Comment: @Paulw11 , interesting point. My understanding from that statement was that the app developer can't "tip" the users (perhaps this is to counter issue where app developer tipping users in exchange for reviews?). Anyway, on the same guideline (3.1.1), they mentioned as follows "Apps and their metadata may use in-app purchase currencies to enable customers to “tip” digital content providers in the app."